# Updating every row in a listview in a timer in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

This is my only component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, ListView, StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';
import Row from './row'
import TimerMixin from 'react-timer-mixin';


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 20,
  },
});


class ListViewDemo extends React.Component {

updateState(){
    console.log("stae updation")
  }
 componentDidMount() {
       console.log("mount");
       //timer.setTimeout(this, this.updateState, 1000);

    }

 componentWillUnmount() {
   console.log("unmount");
    //timer.clearTimeout(this);
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    let data = [{
      "name": {
      "symbol": "Hello",
      "tick": 1
    }}, 
    {
      "name": {
      "symbol": "World",
      "tick": 0
    }}]

    this.state = {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(data),
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <ListView
        style={styles.container}
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={(data) => <Row {...data} />}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default ListViewDemo;
```

Now, I want to update each of the row's ticker by incrementing it by 1 inside a timer every second. Couple of issues I'm facing is binding a function that can update the state, and getting a mixin library working for es6. Any help, please?

Comment: Hello RandomGuy, have you tried the solution I added below? Are you encountering any issues with the Row info in a different component?

Answer (score 0):

This is a working example where info is updated in every row after pressing `Start` and that uses TimerMixin.

I used some extra vars on state to make this work quickly.

It might be possible to extract data directly from dataSource (without using the updatedData var) but I haven't discovered that yet.

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, ListView, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';
import TimerMixin from 'react-timer-mixin';



const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        marginTop: 20,
    },
    button: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderRadius: 5,
        padding: 5,
        borderColor: 'black',
        marginTop: 10,
        height: 40
    },
    buttonText: {
        flex: 1,
        alignSelf: 'center',
        fontSize: 20
    }
});


class ListViewDemo extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
        let data = [{
            "name": {
                "symbol": "Hello",
                "tick": 1
            }},
            {
                "name": {
                    "symbol": "World",
                    "tick": 0
                }}]

        this.state = {
            timerStarted: false,
            updatedData: data,
            dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(data),
        };

    }

    onTimerStart() {
        if (this.state.timerStarted) {
            this.setState({timerStarted: false});
            return TimerMixin.clearInterval(this.state.timer);
        }

        var timer = TimerMixin.setInterval(
            () => {
                data = [{
                    "name": {
                        "symbol": "Hello",
                        "tick": this.state.updatedData[0].name.tick+1
                    }},
                    {
                        "name": {
                            "symbol": "World",
                            "tick": this.state.updatedData[1].name.tick+1
                        }}]
                this.setState({
                    timerStarted: true,
                    updatedData: data,
                    dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(data)
                })
            }, 1000
        )

        this.setState({timer: timer});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <ListView
                    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                    renderRow={(rowData) => <Text> {rowData.name.symbol} {rowData.name.tick}</Text> }
                />
                <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button}
                    underlayColor={'gray'}
                    onPress={this.onTimerStart.bind(this)}>
                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Start</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>

        );
    }

}


export default ListViewDemo;
```